# JSP AJAX MYSQL countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want To design a webpage which if a customer takes a subscription package of 2 hours, then the webpage appear for 2 hour with count down timer synchronized with MySQL database.
how to do this in jsp and servlet
what is the best way to do this type of count down timer.
can ajax be used.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code... some table structures maybe...

Comment: you can just serve the client a time, and they can count down to that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

When customer apply or start to consume the package (onSomeClickAction), create a custom session state control Table on MySQL and register the right time befor display the content page:

```
    INSERT INTO my_control_table (userid, package, duration..., started, ended) 
VALUES (121,'MYPACK', 120,..., NOW(), NULL);
...etc
```

> started and ended columns = table colunms of DATETIME Type. 
>   duration = integer number of minutes or DATETIME with time limit.

Now you have to create a JSP (checkpacktime.jsp) to anwswer the Ajax call.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page import="java.net.URLDecoder, java.net.URLEncoder" %>

    String userid = "";
    String packageid = "";

    if (request.getParameter("userid") != null)
        userid = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("userid").trim(), "UTF-8");
    if (request.getParameter("packageid") != null)
        packageid = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("packageid").trim(), "UTF-8");

    //MYSQL Query part----

    //Compare the started column with duration
    ....

    //The result
    if(resultok){
       // return a flag or the remaining timer to sync with 
       //your counter via javascript. (you can use JSON)
       ....
    }else{
       out.print("ENDED");
    }
```

In the target html add this script to check if the time is up and redirect to an Session Ended html page..(with some custom message to user)

```
    <%
       // Here you must execute a MySQL query to check the permissions table
      //and if user can access this content (like in checkpacktime.jsp)
      //If time is up then redirect to endsession.jsp..

      ...query CODE
      if(notOK)
         response.sendRedirect("endsession.jsp"); 
    %>

    <script>

    var synccounter = 0; //if you plant to sync with server
    var timeleft = 120 * 60; //initialize the regressive counter


    // check the state every 30 seconds
    setInterval(function(){checkcounter();}, 30 *1000);

    function checkcounter(){
       var params="userid=the_user_id&packageid=your_package_id";
       $.ajax({url:"checkpacktime.jsp",
           type:"POST",
           data:params,
           success: function(result){
              if(result != null && result.trim().equals("ENDED")){
                  window.location.href='endsession.jsp';
              }else{
                  synccounter = result.trim();
              }
           }
       });
    }

    //Another setInterval to refresh the timer each second 
    setInterval(function(){refreshtimer();}, 1000);

    function refreshtimer(){
        var myclock = $("#myclock");
        ... convert to mm:ss...
        myclock.value = <converted String>;

        timeleft--;  //decrement counter
    }
    </script>
```

This is a very basic solution, you must improve some security issues, you can disable right mouse click and avoid anyone to access the HTML code to protect content...you can encode content...

You can drive it to Object Oriented creating a Check.class with some methods returning query results..

But this is a simple way to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Send a start time and maybe an end time and be done with it. You can animate it however you want in javascript, or just with text.

Have the server stop serving that client after the time in the database has passed.

Now does it need to work in different timezones? :)